# PostgreSQL - Select on View with TWO Distinct Columns

Tags: postgresql, select, view, distinct

I have a view, invoices_psn_sw:

```
CREATE VIEW invoices_psn_sw
AS SELECT invoices.invoice_number, invoices.shipping_tracking_number, product_serial_numbers.product_serial_number, 
    software.license_number
FROM invoices
LEFT OUTER JOIN product_serial_numbers ON invoices.shipping_tracking_number = product_serial_numbers.shipping_tracking_number
LEFT OUTER JOIN software ON invoices.shipping_tracking_number = software.shipping_tracking_number;
```

The pkey for invoices is invoice_number. One invoice can have many product_serial_numbers and software and they are joined with the fkey shipping_tracking_number from invoices.

The problem is, the output shows every possible combination of product_serial_number, license_number, etc.

I can do;

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (product_serial_number)
```

but what I need is distinct for both product_serial_number and license_number.

If I have 3 license_numbers and 2 product_serial_numbers sharing one shipping_tracking_number, it will display a total of 6 records. I want it to display the least possible - in this case, 3.

Extra code (abbreviated):

```
CREATE TABLE Product_Serial_Numbers (
    product_serial_number varchar(32) CONSTRAINT product_serial_number_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    job_number varchar(32) REFERENCES Jobs(job_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL,
    shipping_tracking_number varchar(64) REFERENCES Shipping(tracking_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE TABLE Software (
    license_number varchar(32) CONSTRAINT license_number_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
    job_number varchar(32) REFERENCES Jobs(job_number) ON UPDATE CASCADE ON DELETE SET NULL
);

CREATE RULE invoices_psn_sw_insert
AS ON INSERT TO invoices_psn_sw
DO INSTEAD
(INSERT INTO invoices(invoice_number, shipping_tracking_number)
VALUES (NEW.invoice_number, NEW.shipping_tracking_number);
UPDATE product_serial_numbers SET shipping_tracking_number = NEW.shipping_tracking_number WHERE product_serial_number = NEW.product_serial_number1;
...
UPDATE product_serial_numbers SET shipping_tracking_number = NEW.shipping_tracking_number WHERE product_serial_number = NEW.product_serial_number30;
UPDATE software SET shipping_tracking_number = NEW.shipping_tracking_number WHERE license_number = NEW.sw_license_number1;
...
UPDATE software SET shipping_tracking_number = NEW.shipping_tracking_number WHERE license_number = NEW.sw_license_number10;
);
```

Thanks

Comment: *"...what I need is distinct for both product_serial_number and license_number."* If you have three license numbers and two product serial numbers, you have six distinct combinations. Three rows probably isn't possible without excluding information. (And you can use inner joins here.) The most likely problem is that there's some kind of relationship between products and licenses that *you* know about, but that the dbms *doesn't* know about. You probably need another table. Paste CREATE TABLE and INSERT statements into your question.

Comment: You're right, actually. Both the software and product_serial_numbers table share the same fkey for job_number. I can't believe I didn't think about that.